# Ember - Displaying API response data on Template.hbs

Tags: ember.js

I'm very new to Ember - highly appreciated if anyone can assist. I need to display the network request response:

This is my `port` route:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        this.store.findRecord('node', params.node_id).then((res) => {
            var port = res.ports.arrangedContent.currentState;
            console.log(port);
            return port;      
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the port model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var ports = {
    label: DS.attr('string'),
    mode: DS.attr('string'),
    node_name: DS.attr('string'),
    port_csid: DS.attr('string'),
    proxied_ssh_url: DS.attr('string'),
    web_terminal_url: DS.attr('string'),
    runtime_status: DS.belongsTo('nodeRuntimeStatus', {async: false}),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('node', {async: false}),
};

export default DS.Model.extend(ports);
```

below is the template:

```
{{#each item in model}}
    <span>
       {{item.label}}
    </span>
{{/each}}
```

API call happens and I can console.log the ports (array) but no sure why I get nothing to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found what was wrong with this.

Firstly, as Lux mentioned, I was missing a `return` in my `model()`.

Second problem was with `each` helper. 
I changed the template from `{{#each item in model}}` to `{{#each model as |item|}}` and resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a `return` in your `model()` hook. So you should do:

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('node', params.node_id).then((res) => {
        var port = res.ports.arrangedContent.currentState;
        console.log(port);
        return port;      
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the quick response - unfortunately the issue is still there - nothing is rendering